# Fabric CA bootstrap Identity can be admin for organisation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have one organisation org0 with fabric CA ca-0, We  bootstap the CA identity  which i showed in below command:

```
sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

when this command is executed its create the Admin for fabric CA. 
Is it same has organisation Admin or we need to create the different admin for organisation.
I am asking this because now i have one organisation and fabric ca config has show below, which is CA server config file. This CA admin which enrolled generate the certificate which has root access for all affiliation.

```
registry:
 maxenrollments: -1
    # Contains identity information which is used when LDAP is disabled
 identities:
 - name: <<<adminUserName>>>
   pass: <<<adminPassword>>>
   type: client
   affiliation: ""
   attrs:
      hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
      hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
      hf.Revoker: true
      hf.IntermediateCA: true
      hf.GenCRL: true
      hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"
      hf.AffiliationMgr: true


  affiliations:
 org1:
  - department1
  - department2
```

Questions:

1. If I use fabric CA admin, has organisation admin, what all issue i might face.
2. Do i need to create the separate Admin of org1.
3. when i create the user for organisation with roletype member/client what is a different between member and client role type. Because when i enroll admin for fabric ca, the role type will be client.